# .net core Angular SPA : Redirect to error page if policy defined in Start up page is not succeed

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, angular, asp.net-core

I am using Latest SPA template in Visual Studio. Which do not have views folder and **index.cshtml** file.
There is **index.html** file and is under angular client app folder which has  tag.
Also there is **Error.cshtml** file under pages folder. So structure looks like below:
[image]

So In policy handler i have written following code for redirection :

```
 protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, Requirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, Roles.Admin))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            var authFilterContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
            authFilterContext.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("AccessDenied", "Account", null);
        }


        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

And in Account Controller i have following action :

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult AccessDenied()
    {
      return this.View("/Pages/Error");
    }
```

> But the action fails with error saying the error view not found.

Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });

        services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
        {
            x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        });

        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(this.Configuration);
        services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, AppInsightsInitializer>();

        // Adds services required for using options.
        services.AddOptions();

        services.Configure<AppSettingsConfig>(this.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));




        var azureAdConfig = new AzureAdConfig();


        if (this.RequireAAD())
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
            });
        }
        else
        {
            services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
            {
            });
        }

        // Add Authentication services.
        if (this.RequireAAD())
        {
            // Configure the OWIN pipeline to use cookie auth.
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()

            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = azureAdConfig.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = azureAdConfig.ClientSecret;
                options.Authority = string.Format(azureAdConfig.AADInstance, azureAdConfig.Tenant);
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
                options.Resource = azureAdConfig.ResourceURI_Graph;
                // PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration["AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
                options.Events = new AuthEvents(azureAdConfig, connectionStringsConfig);
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Authenticated", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser());

                options.AddPolicy(
                    PolicyNames.Require,
                    policy =>
                    {
                        policy.AddRequirements(new Requirement(this.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("AppSettings:Enable")));
                        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                        policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    });
            });
        }

        this.ConfigureStore(services);

        if (this.RequireAAD())
        {
            services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                 .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                 .Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new Microsoft​.AspNetCore​.Mvc​.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                config.Filters.Add(new Microsoft​.AspNetCore​.Mvc​.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter(PolicyNames.Require));
                config.Filters.Add(typeof(ExceptionFilter));
            });
        }
        else
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }
        services.AddAutoMapper();
        // For accessing appinsights for dependency injection?
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, TelemetryClient tc, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        var azureAdConfig = new AzureAdConfig();
        this.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:AzureAd").Bind(azureAdConfig);
        this.SetupStore(app);

        app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps());

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        // TODO . Switch
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));

       app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "static",
              template: "");
        });

        app.UseProtectFolder(new ProtectFolderOptions
        {
            Path = "/Clientapp",
            PolicyName = "Authenticated"
        });

        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 1, seconds: 30);
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you upload Startup.cs file ?

Comment: @TonyNgo sure. but it is with so much of configuration

Answer (score 0):

Although pages & view files share the same `.cshtml` file extension, pages are quite different from the plain view files. Be aware the `/Pages/Error.cshtml`(and the related `Error.cshtml.cs`) is a `page` that will be compiled into a MVC action. In other words, it handles requests directly. Pages are actually not the view files that are used by controllers.

As for you question, the easiest way is to change your code as below:

```
authFilterContext.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("AccessDenied", "Account", null);
authFilterContext.Result = new RedirectToPageResult("/Error", "GET", null);
```

Or if you want to make use of the `AccessDenied` action, you could also change this action as below:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult AccessDenied()
{
    return this.View("/Pages/Error");
    return new RedirectToPageResult("/Error", "GET", null);
}
```

Comment: @itiminus i will try this. if you want to check start up i have added that

Comment: @SagarK I think there's no need to check the `startup.cs` for the present(unless you changed the MVC services). I test my code and it works fine for me. If my reply doesn't work for you, feel free to update me.

Comment: @SagarK Did you get routed to `/Error?handler=GET`?

Comment: no change in URL. Do i need to write action in controller ?

Comment: @SagarK Did you send the request with ajax? If that's case, the url won't be redirected by default unless you read the `Location: /Error?hander=GET` header in the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195555/discussion-between-itminus-and-sagar-k).

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code into this

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public IActionResult AccessDenied()
 {
    return RedirectToPage("/Error");
 }
```

Comment: it is getting into infinite loop.same action is getting called again and again